# PowerQuery - There's a problem with the clipboard, but you can still paste... Error repeating many time during query refresh

Tags: excel, powerquery

Whenever I refresh my data queries (Quite large) I am getting the following error some number of times seemingly randomly repeating until the table eventually loads the rows. I have to click ok or hold ok until it is done. It can be a 30min delay per table.

I have googled and directly searched stack overflow to no avail.  Within the general settings I disabled preview and its had no impact.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As I can see you are using Windows 10, you can try turning off "clipboard history" in settings > system > clipboard.

This worked for me when I had the same error message in MS Excel, so I assume it will work here as well.

I have read that the problem is due to the clipboard being locked by other running applications.

See similar questions (without solutions) [here](https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/40394503-fix-the-problem-with-clipboard-mess) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_win10-mso_o365b/theres-a-problem-with-the-clipboard-but-you-can/6a71d82b-2209-4d32-8c7b-f963353564b3).